# Unable to link between jquery and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a project.
I have done some designing.I have taken one form , In that form i have taken some information like name,address,phno etc.
And lastly i have taken Country ,State and City.

What i am trying to do is if i will select Country then automatically it will display the corresponding States of that Country ,after selecting the States it will automatically display the corresponding Cities of that State.

I have seen one site ,where they have done like that.(it is working fine)

If you want to see then please check it http://jsfiddle.net/fRuhn/881/

Same thing i am doing in Macromedia Dreamweaver 8,but i am not getting the output

coding i have done

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#select1").change(function () {
            if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
                /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
                $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
            }
            var id = $(this).val();
            var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
            $('#select2').html(options);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="change();">
        <option value="1">Fruit</option>
        <option value="2">Animal</option>
        <option value="3">Bird</option>
        <option value="4">Car</option>
    </select>

    <select name="select2" id="select2">
        <option value="1">Banana</option>
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="1">Orange</option>
        <option value="2">Wolf</option>
        <option value="2">Fox</option>
        <option value="2">Bear</option>
        <option value="3">Eagle</option>
        <option value="3">Hawk</option>
        <option value="4">BWM
            <option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Will anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

My problem is if i will select fruit then it is not displaying the fruit item,it is displaying all the item.

Problem in my coding is i am not able to call jquery function , how to call that from the select tag ?

Thanks to all.
Binay

Comment: Where is the library loaded?

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: it is working in fiddle after adding above Jquery refrence http://jsfiddle.net/fRuhn/881/

Comment: In fiddle they have done direcltly,without calling any function ,i am not getting one thing ,if i am doing in my local system then how to call that jqueryfunction ?

Comment: Yes Mr. Anoop i have checked, it is working fine,Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You have not included the jQuery libraries.

Add this in the `<head>` above the first jQuery functions:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply. I am new to JQuery.Sorry ,i had this line in my coding i forgot to write .No same output, it is not fetching the particular item.I am thinking the problem is while calling may be ,can  you check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Like @dwhite.me said, you havent incluse jquery in your code. Include it. Also you should wrap the code in dom ready. Other wise script will execute when there is no element with id `#select1`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#select1").change(function () {
                if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
                    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
                    $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
                }
                var id = $(this).val();
                var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
                $('#select2').html(options);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="change();">
        <option value="1">Fruit</option>
        <option value="2">Animal</option>
        <option value="3">Bird</option>
        <option value="4">Car</option>
    </select>

    <select name="select2" id="select2">
        <option value="1">Banana</option>
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="1">Orange</option>
        <option value="2">Wolf</option>
        <option value="2">Fox</option>
        <option value="2">Bear</option>
        <option value="3">Eagle</option>
        <option value="3">Hawk</option>
        <option value="4">BWM
            <option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Comment: You can always add your jQuery and Javascript at bottom of page.